# Why is RSA encryption version 1.0 not specified in an RFC?

Tags: encryption, rsa

I saw that there are three RSA encryption versions, as follows:

- RSA encryption version 1.5 ([RFC 2313](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313))
- RSA cryptography specification version 2.0 ([RFC 2347](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2347))
- RSA cryptography specification version 2.1 ([RFC 3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447))

Why is there no RFC for RSA version 1.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RSA is and was specified by the [PKCS#1 specifications of RSA laboratories](http://netherlands.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/pkcs-rsa-cryptography-standard.htm). PKCS are the ["Public Key Cryptography Standards" by RSA Laboratories](http://netherlands.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/public-key-cryptography-standards.htm), now part of EMC<sup>2</sup>. The [RSA PKCS#1 v1.5](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/ascii/pkcs-1.asc) is the lowest publicly released version of RSA by RSA labs that can currently be downloaded.

Version 1.0 to 1.4 are working drafts as specified in the PKCS#1 documents themselves and at least the inital PKCS#1 RFC 2313 as well:

- Versions 1.0–1.3 were distributed to participants in RSA Data Security, Inc.'s Public-Key Cryptography Standards meetings in February and March 1991.
- Version 1.4 was part of the June 3, 1991 initial public release of PKCS. Version 1.4 was published as NIST/OSI Implementors' Workshop document SEC-SIG-91-18.

Although the RSA standards have been defined by RSA Laboratories they are likely to have been influenced by the participants to the meetings and workshops.

The RFC's are simply a reiteration of the PKCS#1 standards that have undergone public scrutiny. They are not in control by a single private party. So the standard may be identical, but it is at least open. In general the RFC's just keep to the PKCS#1 specifications, but at least in principle follow up documents may deviate from the specifications by RSA.

Comment: [PKCS#1 v1.5](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/ascii/pkcs-1.asc) ends with a Revision history, which explains what version 1.0-1.3 and 1.4 have been, and the differences since 1.4

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks!  your answer really help me! So happy to learn it! Also, I found PKCS#1 V2.2 was updated in 2012( http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/pkcs/files/h11300-wp-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard.pdf).

Comment: @MattElson 2.2 is a very minor change, it only adds SHA-224, SHA-512/256 and SHA-512/384 to the mix of hashing algorithms. You can see this from the changelog at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry everybody, you may have to input those URL's into the wayback archive, because the current owners of RSA have not deemed it necessary to keep them around.